# SonarQube and Jacoco failed to identify the kotlin-classes directory

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sonarqube, jacoco

I am using Jacoco **v0.8.4** and Sonarcube **v2.7.1**.

> I am using the following configuration for SonarCube.

```
property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
property "sonar.binaries","build/intermediates/javac,app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes"
property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/intermediates/javac,app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes"
property "sonar.tests", "src/test/java" // where the tests are located
property "sonar.java.test.binaries", "build/intermediates/javac,app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes"
property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "build/jacoco/testDevDebugUnitTest.exec"
property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
property "sonar.android.lint.report", "build/reports/lint results.xml"
```

The SonarCube analysis failed with reason as Invalid value for **sonar.java.binaries**

`> No files nor directories matching 'app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes'`

But *'app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes'* exist in my project folder.

But, If I remove `kotlin` things from the property then it provides the coverage for Java files successfully.

Am I doing anything wrong for Kotlin coverage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you also need to add you build variant folder in pathlike below

```
property "sonar.java.test.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/test/, app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/<BuildVariant>UnitTest"
property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/<BuildVariant>/, app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/<BuildVariant>/"
property "sonar.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/<BuildVariant>/, app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/<BuildVariant>/"
```

and one more thing try to avoid using file name with whitespace like `lint results.xml`

Comment: Hi Archit Can you share a sample project with test coverage visible on sonar which shows kotlin classes and test cases are visible on it's dashboard ?